# Warning on modal close

Tags: modal-dialog, warnings, bootstrap-modal

On a page, I'm going to have a bootstrap modal with a form that will not be necessary to be all filled in one go.

Is there a way that, when the user hits the close button on the modal, to have a warning popup with confirm close and cancel close?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### *Update (Bootstrap 5)*

According to the [migration guide to v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#javascript):

> "all data attributes for all JavaScript plugins are now namespaced to
> help distinguish Bootstrap functionality from third parties and your
> own code. For example, we use **data-bs-toggle instead of data-toggle**"

In short, simply replace all data-* attributes by data-bs-* attributes for this to work in Bootstrap 5.

### *Original answer (Bootstrap <5)*

Assuming you have 2 modals

1. one for form (first modal) and 2nd for warning to close modal (both modals)
2. and using bootstrap default modal behaviour `data-toggle` and `data-target` to invoke the first modal (with form)

**Important:**

1. Make sure you add `data-backdrop="static"` and `data-keyboard="false"` in Form Modal trigger button so it will not be closed when click outside the modal otherwise the whole solution is useless.
2. Make sure you add `data-backdrop="false"` in Warning Modal so there will be only one back-drop for first modal.

**Changes:**

1. Remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from both Header / Footer `Close Button` of Form Modal
2. Add `data-dismiss="modal"` to Warning Modal `Cancel Close button` just only to dismiss Warning modal
3. Add class `closefirstmodal` in Form Modal Header / Footer `Close button` to invoke the warning modal with [jQuery click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [bootstrap modal event listener](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)
4. Add class `confirmclosed` in Warning Modal `Confirm close Button` which will use to close both Form / Warning Modals with [jQuery click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and hide both Modal via jQuery `$('#Modalselector').modal('hide')`

Modal's HTML

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Form" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal With Form -->
<div id="Form" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close closefirstmodal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some Form Elements Here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default closefirstmodal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal With Warning -->
<div id="Warning" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This Is A Warning Message</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger confirmclosed">Confirm Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS with B.S modal Event Listener (You can skip the event listener but I prefer this way)
Note: Event listener must be registered before the modal is shown, otherwise it won't fire for the first confirmation.

```js
//jQuery and Bootstrap Lib's always comes first
$(document).ready(function () { //Dom Ready
    $('.closefirstmodal').click(function () { //Close Button on Form Modal to trigger Warning Modal
        $('#Warning').on('show.bs.modal', function () { //Register `show` event listener before showing modal
            $('.confirmclosed').click(function () { //Waring Modal Confirm Close Button
                $('#Warning').modal('hide'); //Hide Warning Modal
                $('#Form').modal('hide'); //Hide Form Modal
            });
        }).modal('show'); //Show Warning Modal
    });
});
```

[Fiddle example-1](http://jsfiddle.net/97qp8r4g/)

JS without B.S modal Event Listener

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.closefirstmodal').click(function () {
        $('#Warning').modal('show');
    });

    $('.confirmclosed').click(function () {
        $('#Warning').modal('hide');
        $('#Form').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example-2](http://jsfiddle.net/54y82xn9/2/)